# Benchmarking function variations

Tags: performance, assembly, benchmarking

I'm trying to benchmark two variations of one of my functions. Namely, these functions are for displaying integer values on the command line.

The first of these uses my own implementation and prints from high to low, this is it actually determines the first digit to print and prints it, in contrary to the second method.

The second function prints from low to high, I found this somewhere else on stackoverflow (I'll add that sometime). This determines the last digit to print first, and so pushes all digits to the stack before printing them all in one go.

This is the benchmark I'm running:

```
format PE64

include 'win64a.inc'

entry start

section '.code' code readable executable
start:
    xor rax, rax
    xor rcx, rcx
    xor rdx, rdx
    xor r10, r10
    xor r11, r11
    xor r12, r12
    xor r13, r13
    xor r14, r14
    xor r15, r15

    mov r11, 1000
    mov r12, r11
    sub rsp, 32

    .l1:
        mov rcx, 12345
        call rdtsc64x
        mov r13, rax

        call printInt1 ;tested method

        call rdtsc64x
        sub rax, r13
        add r14, rax

        dec r11
        jnz .l1

    mov r11, r12

    .l2:
        mov rcx, 12345
        call rdtsc64x
        mov r13, rax

        call printInt2 ;tested method

        call rdtsc64x
        sub rax, r13
        add r15, rax

        dec r11
        jnz .l2

    mov rcx, print1
    call [printf]
    mov rcx, r14
    call printInt
    call newline

    mov rcx, print2
    call [printf]
    mov rcx, r15
    call printInt
    call newline
    call newline

    sub r14, r15
    mov rcx, r14
    call printInt
    call newline

    invoke ExitProcess, 0

log10:
    mov rax, 1
    mov r9, 10
    mov r8, 0

    .l1:
        mul r9
        inc r8
        cmp rcx, rax
        jge .l1

    dec r8
    mov rax, r8
ret

exp10:
    mov rax, 1
    mov r8, 10

    .l1:
        sub rcx, 1
        jl .e1
            mul r8
            jmp .l1
    .e1:
ret

printInt:
    push r12
    push r13
    sub rsp, 32

    mov r12, rcx

    test rcx, rcx
    jns .e1
        mov rcx, 45
        neg r12
        call [putchar]    
    .e1:

    mov rcx, r12
    call log10
    mov r13, rax

    .l1:
        mov rcx, r13
        call exp10

        mov rcx, rax
        mov rax, r12
        mov rdx, 0
        div rcx

        mov rcx, rax
        mov r12, rdx
        add rcx, 0x30
        call [putchar]

        dec r13
        jnz .l1

    add rsp, 32
    pop r13
    pop r12
ret

printInt1:
    push r12
    push r13
    sub rsp, 32

    mov r12, rcx

    test rcx, rcx
    jns .e1
        mov rcx, 45
        neg r12
        call [putchar]    
    .e1:

    mov rcx, r12
    call log10
    mov r13, rax

    .l1:
        mov rcx, r13
        call exp10

        mov rcx, rax
        mov rax, r12
        mov rdx, 0
        div rcx

        mov rcx, rax
        mov r12, rdx
        add rcx, 0x30
        call [putchar]

        dec r13
        jnz .l1

    add rsp, 32
    pop r13
    pop r12
ret

printInt2:
    push r12
    push r13
    sub rsp, 32

    mov r12, rcx
    mov r13, 10

    test r12, r12
    jns .e1
        neg r12
        mov rcx, 45
        ;call [putchar]   
    .e1:

    .l1:
        mov rax, r12
        mov rdx, 0
        div r13

        mov rcx, rdx
        add rcx, 0x30
        mov r12, rax
        ;call [putchar]
        test r12, r12
        jnz .l1

    add rsp, 32
    pop r13
    pop r12
ret

newline:
sub rsp, 32
mov rcx, 0xa
call [putchar]
mov rcx, 0xd
call [putchar]
add rsp, 32
ret

rdtsc64x:
rdtsc
shl rdx, 32
add rax, rdx
mov rdx, 0
ret

section '.rdata' data readable writeable
print1 db 'printInt downwards: ', 0
print2 db 'printInt upwards: ', 0

section '.idata' import data readable writeable

library kernel, 'kernel32.dll',\
    msvcrt, 'msvcrt.dll'

import kernel, ExitProcess, 'ExitProcess'
import msvcrt, printf, 'printf',\
    putchar, 'putchar'
```

The bottom up approach seems to outperform the top down method by 15000 cycles.

Do you think my benchmark is good, if not could you give me some advice on my benchmark? Also, I would like to know if you had any ideas on optimizing some of my functions.

Finally, I disassembled the code to see what FASM did with it, and it hadn't even optimized the littlest bit. Is this just something that no ASM compiler does, is this just FASM (and what compilers would optimize then?) or am I missing something.

Comment: initial observations: [zero registers with `xor`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/which-is-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and).  In `printInt` v1, save/restore some call-preserved registers (like `rbx`) in the function prologue/epilogue, and use them instead of doing so much `push`/`pop` around every function call.  Why do some of your functions (like `modulus`) zero some scratch registers (like `rcx`) before returning?  The standard calling conventions let you leave garbage in call-clobbered registers.

Comment: Yeah, most of that code is old by now as I've optimized  some stuff. Thanks for reminding me of using`xor` though.